# Trying to store information

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I want to save all the users' registered ids to a text file. If the user gives 9 users, then I want it to store all the information. But when I run the code and finish it seems to be overwriting all the information. I know there is something that I'm missing. Can someone please help me?

```
student_count = int(input("how many students are registering?:"))
reg_form = []

for x in range(student_count):
    
   if student_count >= 0:
       registered_user = input("Please enter your I.D number for registeration: ")
       id_information = [registered_user + reg_form]
       student_count - 1
   
student_count2 = str(student_count)


with open ("reg_form.txt", 'w') as f:
     f.write(registered_user + "\n")
     
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it that way:

```
student_count = int(input("how many students are registering?:"))
counter = 0

for x in range(student_count):
    
   if counter < student_count + 1:
       registered_user = input("Please enter your I.D number for registeration: ")
       counter += 1


       reg_form = open('reg_form.txt', 'a') 
       reg_form.write(registered_user + "\n")
       reg_form.close()
```

You basically do not need reg_form and student_count2.

It appears that you use write mode on every iteration of the loop, which overwrites existing file. You need to use append mode like this:

```
open('reg_form.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: Thank you you really helped me